# How to use nc for transmit data in one command or in a shell script?

Tags: mysql, linux

For remote backup,I want to use nc utility to transmit data for a streaming backup with xtrabackup.As Follows,

```
nc -l 1025 > /data/backups/backup.tar &
ssh root@192.168.0.110 "innobackupex --stream=tar ./ | bzip2 - | nc 192.168.0.100 1025"
```

When I run these commands seperately,it ended successfully.

```
#!/bin/bash

nc -l 1025 > /data/backups/backup.tar &
ssh root@192.168.0.110 "innobackupex --stream=tar ./ | bzip2 - | nc 192.168.0.100 1025"
```

But when I write them together in a shell script and execute the script, there came across the following errors,

[image]

Comment: You should add the console output as part of your question.

Comment: The first nc proces in your script would block waiting for an incoming connection, only after that the ssh command would be executed. It might be different if you append a `&` to the first line to execute it as a background job.

Comment: It's my fault because when I edit this question,I forgot to append a & to the first line.Now it has been fixed.So the quetion is not resolved.

Comment: try using `nc -l -p 1025`, depending on what `nc` it might not listen on port 1025...

Comment: Why?It doesn't work.